# Storing selected Drop Down Item in Session Storage

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a splash page with various form elements. One of which a DropDownList. I want to store the index, or preferably the ID as its using SQL Data Source to populate it. Here's the aspx:

```
</asp:DropDownList>
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="NationalitiesSQL" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString %>" 
SelectCommand="SELECT [Description] FROM [Nationality]">
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

I've tried:

```
Session["Nationality"] = Convert.ToInt32(nationality.SelectedValue);
```

Any help would be appreciated as I'm relatively new to C# and ASP.Net.

Oh, the reason I need to to this is to insert into a DB through an Insert but the Nationality column returns a NULL.

Comment: What did you expect to happen that didn't? What is your question?

Comment: What you are asking isn't clear? Can you post some code?

Comment: Essentially, how can I store the selected item index out of the Drop Down List in Integer type in a Session Variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Session values are of type Object.

Your conversion when writing to session is not necessary (in fact useless) simply do

```
Session["Nationality"] = nationality.SelectedValue;
```

When you read back the value you need to cast Object to Int:

```
myRetrievedInt = (int)Session["Nationality"]
```

See this [msdn entry.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/03sekbw5(v=vs.140).aspx)

Answer (score 1):

I notice that you are developing a Web Forms project. From my point of view put session for this type of information always leads to mistakes and confusion when the session begins to grow. I recommend you  to enable and use routing. This is also possible in web forms.

If you do not know what routing is you can give a look to this resources:

- [Introduction to Routing 1](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668201(v=vs.140).aspx)
- [Introduction to Routing 2](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-aspnet-45-web-forms/url-routing)
- [Walkthrough: Using ASP.NET Routing in a Web Forms Application](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd329551(v=vs.100).aspx)
- [ScottGu's tutorial](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/url-routing-with-asp-net-4-web-forms-vs-2010-and-net-4-0-series)
- [Other ASP.NET Web Forms Routing Resources](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/overview/routing)

Comment: Thanks for the useful info! I'll definitely take a look at Routing!